# Change the value of once cell based the value of drop down list

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have a list of values on Sheet 1 and drop down list on sheet 2 which has values given in sheet 1.

Ex: On sheet 1, I have values as Rack, Dept, server, etc. (I have created named range as council).
On Sheet 2, B17 have drop down list with values provided above.

Now, on Sheet 2, B18 I have to create a drop down list. 
So, if the user selects B17 as Rack. B18 value should be "Full"
User selects B17 as Dept. B18 should be "Carass"
User selects B17 as Server. B18 should be "Rizon" etc.

Values on B18 will not change and will be constant.
How will I accomplish this? Do I have to hardcode using VBA.

Note: I don't want a drop down list on B18. Hence I am confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think the simplest thing to do would be to add your fixed values that correspond to your drop down choices next to them in sheet 1 and then use a vlookup formula with an iferror in B18 on sheet 2 so that it is either blank or populated with your corresponding values. The below assumes your choices are in A4 to A6 and your responses are in B4 to B6 in sheet 1. Place the formula in B18 on sheet 2:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($B$17,Sheet1!$A$4:$B$6,2,0),"")
```

This should work fine.

EDIT further to comments:

```
=IFERROR(IF(AND($B$17="Rack",$D$23>DATEVALUE("01/12/2006")),"",VLOOKUP($B$17,Council,2,0)),"")
```

The above assumes that your Full result is in the named range and then just puts a blank otherwise.

Comment: I am getting an error "A named range you specified cannot be found" . Btw, I am not using named range as per your formula

Comment: I have placed values and responses side by side.

Sheet 1 named as "Taba"
Sheet 2 named as "Tabb"

Values in Taba(sheet1)
Values are from G15 to G31 ( named range as Council)
Responses are from H15 to H31

Drop down list on B17 I have added =Council in data validation
On B18 I am trying to add below formula

=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($B$17,Taba!$G$15:$H$31,2,0),"")

A named range you specified cannot be found.

Comment: Sorry, I got it. my bad...I used it as a formula on cell that helped!! Thank you so so much

Comment: @Matt_Roberts shouldn't it be `;` instead of `,`

Comment: @DragonSamu where would you put a semi colon? Most excel formula operators/conditions are separated by commas I thought.

Comment: @Matt_Roberts in `VBA` yes in the actual formula on the sheet its a semi colon. Mostly one of the errors people get when trying to do it in `VBA`

Comment: @Matt_Roberts. I have one more concern. Please help me. As per my question above if the user selects B17 as Rack. B18 value should be "Full"  Or "Empty". So only for this choice I need either of the 1 response. I cannot use Full or Empty in one cell. How do I place this value?

Comment: @Matt_Roberts, Just to make it simpler to understand. earlier i had once choice and 1 response. Now, only for one of the choices I have 2 responses. Can I still place the responses and value side by side and modify the formula?

Comment: @sady hi, with  vlookup formula you can only usually return 1 response unless you combine this with an if statement and add an additional criteria that lets the formula know which one (Full or Empty) is the correct response. Do you have an additional criteria that would distinguish full or empty?

Comment: @Matt_Roberts. Yes, we had additional criteria. On Cell D23 user has to enter Date range. if he enters 01 Dec 2006 and prior it should show as Full and 01 Dec 2006 and forward, response should be Empty. Does this help?

Comment: @sady amended my answer to compensate for your requirement.

Comment: @Matt_Roberts Brilliant!! We are very close. I am very close to result. Two things which I am confused about, 1. Should put Rack, Full, Empty side by side. 2. Defined named council represents for one column(values). Do I have to define name selecting both values and response? I modified formula as below which gave me a result but not sure if its right way.  =IFERROR(IF(AND($B$17="Rack",$D$23>DATEVALUE("01/12/2006")),"empty",VLOOKUP($B$17,Tabb!G15:H31,2,0)),"")

Comment: @Matt_Roberts. Hope I made sense!! Apologize if it doesn't.

Comment: @sady you have added empty to the formula in the right place, you do not also need to put it next to full in that instance. I assumed your named range included the responses when I edited, your edit should work if this is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

If there's only one value in B18 then have your mapping between what's chosen in B17 and B18 in another range and just use a `VLOOKUP`.